# Rails 4.1 not all e-mails delivered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, redis, actionmailer, sidekiq

After porting a Rails 3.1 application to Rails 4.1.6, only the first few e-mails get delivered. It still works fine on Rails 3.1 on the same machine with the same SMTP server information.

The application sends a customized reminder e-mail to each of about 6 people scheduled to participate in an event. There is a loop that calls an ActionMailer to generate the e-mail and then deliver it.

Only 2 or 3 of the e-mails are actually received although the log shows all of the e-mails being generated and sent.

I tried 'sleep(5)' between sending each e-mail but that didn't make any difference.

I thought sending it asynchronously might fix the problem.

http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/06/26/rails-4-sneak-peek-async-actionmailer.html
suggests adding
self.async = true
to the mailer class but there is an error that the 'async' method is unknown and this doesn't appear in the ActionMailer API docs.

I tried setting up sidekiq and redis (not the most obvious) and using 
UserMailer.delay.reminder1(item, test)
which doesn't fail and the redis server seems to have received the request but no e-mail is received.

Comment: What do the SMTP server's logs say?

Comment: I don't have access to the ISP's SMTP server logs.